# Trying to check if a buffer is empty in C?

Tags: c, buffer

so I'm trying to check if a buffer is empty using C.
And I simply wanted for it to end if the buffer was empty in the "return_character" method. 
Any help is much appreciated. It also needs to return a char obviously in this method as it is declared using char in the function header.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "empty"? Do you mean a string of zero length? Do you mean that the buffer points to nothing? Also: the rest of the code is completely irrelevant, so why are you posting that? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I mean that the buffer is pointing to nothing, shall I post the other files?

Comment: You do not show the definition of `bufferStrcut`, not to mention explain its logic. So it is hard for potential answerers to know how that struct represents an empty buffer. Please explain that. How is an empty buffer represented inside a `bufferStruct`? Also, in order to propose a sensible implementation of `return_character()` please define what the return value in case of an empty buffer should be. What return value do you expect from `return_character()` in case the buffer is empty. Your return value type is `char` which for example does NOT allow to return `EOF`.

Comment: I've updated the question now will all of the individual files of the program. Hopefully this gives slightly greater insight into how it is working

Comment: You need to be clear about the different states of you buffer. Can you post a table which shows for every structure element the value it has for each state, please? This table should include at least rows for "empty buffer", "half-filled buffer", "completely filled buffer".

Comment: I think it's meant to be a very simple command to return the char that the buffer is pointing to and to return EOF if it is not pointing to something. Because this means "End of File", so logically when its not pointing to something, it should have finished the text file.

Comment: It feels like you're just trying to re-implement `fgetc`.  You need to keep track of where you are in the buffer.  eg, read some data and store a pointer to the last valid byte (or, more likely, one past that).  You have another pointer tracking what you've already consumed.  When the two pointers are equal, the buffer is empty.

Comment: `.buffer` is a pointer to char.  The reason that fgetc returns an `int` is so that EOF can be distinguished from a char.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the buffer holds no characters, you can use the strlen() function from string.h (make sure the buffer is \0-terminated after fread().

If you want to check if malloc failed, compare the pointer with NULL. NULL is a special value given to pointers to mean they point to anything.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> char return_character(bufferStruct* buff){
>   char a = a;
>   // this is where I need the help
> …
> ```

If it's just that… Since you chose `(char)EOF` as the end-of-file marker (reminding of CP/M's Ctrl-Z) and you fill the rest of the buffer with it, the function body can simply be:

```
    if (buff->alongBuffer == buff->bufferLength) buffer_refill(buff);
    return buff->buffer[buff->alongBuffer++];
```

Comment: Using `(char)EOF` to mark the end will not work.  `EOF` is an `int`, it won't fit into a `char` in the general case, and is a value specifically chosen such that no actual `char` value will ever be equal to `EOF`.

Comment: @Andrew Henle - Of course it will work, somehow, just as it worked in CP/M, where Ctrl-Z denoted end-of-file, even if it was actually contained in the file. A comment about why and under which circumstances `(char)EOF` would not work were better placed under the question post, since that decision is part of the query.

Comment: *Of course it will work, somehow*  It will work poorly.  There's a reason why functions such as `[f]getc()` return `int` and not `char`.  *even if it was actually contained in the file*  That unreliable behavior is your definition of "it will work"?!?!

Comment: @Andrew Henle - What you write about `EOF` etc. is well-known (maybe not to the querist, but then it seems advisable to address these concerns to him). Concerning my _definition of "it will work"_ and _unreliable behavior_: 1. You surely won't dispute the logical implication _It will work poorly_ => _it will work_, will you? 2. I indeed don't define standard- or implementation-defined behavior as _unreliable_.